# Hexagonal bush?

Tags: identification, trees, planting, shrubs

I have seen the pictured bush today when hiking around [Las Palmas de Gran Canaria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Palmas_De_Gran_Canaria). From a distance, hexagonal patterns are visible: Adjacent branches grow in an almost perfect 45° angle relative to each other.

What plant is this, or what is a strategy for finding that out?

If you need more information, let me know.

[image: bush]
[image: closeup]

**Update:** Below a picture, that I took after @Throsby's answer, for confirmation. It shows the closeup of a bud, plus mating behavior. ;-) This bush is in a different location than the one pictured above.

[image: bud and wasp]

Comment: looks like the crystalline entity!

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a jerk, I feel compelled to point out that hexagons have external angle of 60˚, not 45˚. But never mind; this is a way cool bush.

Comment: @HenryJackson Those are irregular hexagons. ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that it is a great example of a [Launaea Arborescens](https://www.google.com/search?q=Launaea+Arborescens&aq=f&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=fSaHUeziOavh4AOPkoCwAw&biw=1280&bih=645&sei=fyaHUfybLY7b4AOi5IHgCA). The Spanish name is *Aulaga*,  but the English name is a bit contested, either "spiny lettuce" or "barbed wire bush".

According to this [site](http://www.canaryislandflora.com/arid.htm):

> It is a shrub with small branches turned into thorns and up to 70 centimeters high with a few small hairless leaves, lightly lobed. The yellow flowers are grouped in small flower-heads one centimeter in diameter.

Surprisingly, it is a member of the lettuce family.

Here is a picture from the first link of the plant in bloom with yellow flowers, you can see the yellow in the buds in your photo. Very cool find.

[image]

Comment: Thanks also for the link to the [site](http://www.canaryislandflora.com/arid.htm) - very interesting: There are lots of plants here that I've never seen before, i.e. in mainland Europe.

Answer (score 0):

I'd hazard an educated guess at [Corokia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corokia), or Wire Netting Bush, although I can't currently see any of the tiny leaves present. Even so, the haphazard nature of its growth habit and overall coloration point in that direction.

Comment: Thanks for the guess, but - looking at the images of the [Corokia on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corokia), I'd say it's definitely different. Today, I saw more of these bushes, next to cacti, and I don't remember seeing *any* leaves.

Comment: @feklee I agree that the plant in your photo is probably not Corokia. Feeding pressure has pushed couple dozen unrelated New Zealand shrub species to evolve a small leaved, net branching habit similar to *Corokia*. *Coprosma acerosa* looks very like your plant but is probably wrong also since you found your plant on the Canary Islands. My best not-so-educated guess would be *Launaea arborescens*.

Comment: Not one I've heard of, and I'd guess you're right Eric...

Comment: This doesn't look like a very accurate id.

Comment: @J.Musser, well duh... I know it isn't, it was just a guess, as I said in the answer, and an incorrect one at that, but thanks for saying why you downvoted